# R - Adding date to dataframe using c() returns numeric value

Tags: r

When running the code below which is meant to create an end date for a daily time series (next day ahead), I am using `c()` to combine the shifted time series (which when run on its own returns a date format) with the last end date as specified. However, rather than adding `2017-05-09` to the end of it, it returns a numerical value, which while correctly shifted is of little use.

As can be seen in the example below it also does something strange with the last date which is supposed to be added.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
as.Date(portsim$period)

periods <- data.frame(period = portsim$period)
periods$start <- periods$period
periods$end <- c(periods$start[-1], as.Date("2017-05-09"))   ##problematic line

> periods
         period      start   end
1    2011-08-12 2011-08-12     2
2    2011-08-15 2011-08-15     3
3    2011-08-16 2011-08-16     4
4    2011-08-17 2011-08-17     5
5    2011-08-18 2011-08-18     6
6    2011-08-19 2011-08-19     7
7    2011-08-22 2011-08-22     8
8    2011-08-23 2011-08-23     9
9    2011-08-24 2011-08-24    10
10   2011-08-25 2011-08-25    11
...
1432 2017-05-04 2017-05-04  1433
1433 2017-05-05 2017-05-05  1434
1434 2017-05-08 2017-05-08 17295
```

Comment: Does this work `periods$end <- periods$start+1`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr No am afraid not, as it only returns a single date for all fields, and does not add the last end date not found in `period` or `start`.

Comment: That's weird because this works for me: `foo <- data.frame(start = sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 10))` and then I add an end date that is just the start date incremented by a day `foo$end <- foo$start + 1` and that gives the correct result. Does this code work for you?

Comment: I wonder if your dates are actually character or even factors.  Try `str(periods)` to check.  You might want `periods$start <- as.Date(as.character(periods$period))` instead of what you have.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you so much, that was exactly it! Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your dates are actually character or even factors. Try `str(periods)` to check.

If so, then replace your second line with

```
periods$start <- as.Date(as.character(periods$period))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding 1 to the date should work

```
period <- seq(as.Date("2011-08-12", "%Y-%m-%d"), length = 7, # 1 week long
                                                 by = 1) # seq by day
start <- period
periods <- data.frame(period, start)

library(lubridate) # can do it with base R as well
periods$end <- periods$start + days(1)
```